# Difference between retiring and withdrawing a sports team from a season

Tags: sports

What is the correct verb to say when a sports team decides to not take part in the running season: *withdraw* or *retire*?
Is there a difference between *withdrawal* and *retirement* of teams in the sports context?

**Update:**
The regarding sport is handball. Sometimes during the season, teams break up or lose players because of injuries or when many players leave a team.
The context is not a single game, but over the time of a season.

Comment: This depends entirely on the specific sport *and* the context.

Answer (score -1):

In American English, I think *withdraw* would be more appropriate. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withdraw):

> 2.a to remove oneself from participation

*Retire* isn't usually used to refer to a team, it's usually used by individual players, and implies that they're stopping participation permanently. [Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retire):

> 3 to withdraw from one's position or occupation : conclude one's working or professional career

Comment: In British English it's fairly normal to talk about a player retiring from a game. Wimbledon seems to use it a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a clarification that this is American English.

Comment: @DJClayworth Not just Wimbledon, but tennis in general. (American *and* British.)  It has nothing to do with permanence. A player who *retires* from a tennis match is a player who withdraws from the match due to injury. It's not unusual to have at least one (if not more) retirements in any given tennis tournament. A player who retires from *the sport* is something different.

Comment: @JasonBassford That makes sense, I expect America got most of its tennis jargon from England.